# How to use uv_accept in multithread environment?

Tags: libuv

I found that both parameters(server and handle) of `uv_accept` are required in same `uv_loop`. but I want to make new connection handle in a sub thread which has its own `uv_loop`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run an event loop on each worker thread and have a uv_pipe_t to communicate between the master and the workers. Then on the acceptor thread (the one which calls uv_accept) you can send the accepted handle to a worker over a pipe, using uv_write2.